# how to Populate userform from datepicker

Tags: excel, vba, datepicker, userform

I am trying to set up a userform that is populated by using a date picker.  Column A would be a list of dates whilst columns B, C & D for example would be staff who are working on that day.  I cannot seem to find a way to get textbox's 1 through 3 to populate depending on the date that is being picked.  I had a previous form that used numbers, I am not sure how to alter the code to use dates through a date picker though.  Any help would be appreciated

I have a previous spreadsheet that populate via numeric but cant figure out how to use a datepicker rather than textbox1

```
  Dim id As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, flag As Boolean


Sub GetData()

If IsNumeric(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value) Then
     flag = False
     i = 2
     id = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

     Do While Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""

         If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
             flag = True
             For j = 2 To 5
                 UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = Cells(i + 1, j).Value
             Next j
         End If

         i = i + 1

     Loop

     If flag = False Then
         For j = 2 To 5
             UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = ""
         Next j
     End If

Else
     ClearForm
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: So... it's `TextBox` controls, there's no `DatePicker` control involved, right? Are you using 64-bit Office? Are your users using 64-bit Office? `DatePicker` will only work in a 32-bit host application.

Comment: If you *do* have a `DatePicker`, then all you need to do is set its `Value` to some `Date`.

Comment: The original method was using a textbox but want to use a datepicker control for this new one, was hoping it would be as simple as renaming the datepicker textbox1 but it just errors out

Comment: Naming a `DatePicker` control `TextBox1` sounds like a very good way to confuse whoever will be maintaining that code in the future! The date picker's `Value` will be a `Date`, so you'll want a `Date` for `id` (???), not an `Integer`. Does `[ActiveSheet.]Cells(i + 1, 1).Value` contain dates? Your question is unclear and hard to answer without knowing specifically what the problem is. "it just errors out" - *how* and *where*?

Comment: BTW the integer value of today's date is 43,608 - which is well beyond what can fit a 16-bit `Integer` - that code couldn't possibly have been working with a `TextBox` either.

Comment: Hi,  sorry for being dense, ive never worked with a datepicker before, the other values are not dates, just names.

    if Isnumerical(UserForm1.DTPicker1.Value) Then
             flag = False
         i = 2
         id = UserForm1.DTPicker1.Value

Comment: Im assuming a date will not classify as a numerical entry.  could you help with these initial first lines so that if dates were contained downwards in a column and the dates were followed by names in the row that when you pick the date it checks the column, finds the respective date populates the test boxes with the names?

Comment: A `Date` has an internal `Double` representation, but `IsNumeric(Date)` will return `False`, and if you're using a `DatePicker` then `IsDate(DatePicker.Value)` will always be `True` (unless it's a `Variant/Empty`.. been a while since I used a `DatePicker`). As for your code, I've no idea what it's trying to do with `id` values being numbers turning into dates. I think you need to take a step back and re-evaluate what it is that you're trying to do, and explain it clearly with a [mcve] that makes it easy for people to understand what the specific problem is.